# KeyError: '[False False False ... False False False] not found in axis'

Tags: pandas

How to drop rows which satisfies this condition:

`df_covid_big_data.drop(df_covid_big_data['Confirmed'] < df_covid_big_data['Deaths'],axis=0,inplace=True)`

Comment: This looks like a standard `pandas` question, so removing tags `matplotlib , machine-learning, artificial-intelligence`.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, try this:

```py
df_covid_big_data.drop(
    df_covid_big_data[
        df_covid_big_data['Confirmed'] < df_covid_big_data['Deaths']].index,
    inplace=True)
```

Wouldn't it be easier to just reverse the conditions?

```py
df_covid_big_data[df_covid_big_data['Confirmed'] > df_covid_big_data['Deaths']]
```